# Pattern matching on generic abstract type in scala

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-erasure, scala-generics

I have a self-recursive type:

```
trait Problem[P <: Problem[P]] {
  type Solution
}
```

Now, I want to pattern match on `P#Solution`. Let's assume we're within the `case class Foo[P <: Problem[P]]()`:

```
case ExampleCaseClass(s: P#Solution) if conditionApplies() =>
  // do sth

case ExampleCaseClass(s: P#Solution) =>
  // now sth else
```

Of course it fails due to type erasure. Is there any way to make that code compile in scala?

I've seen class/type tags but I'm not really sure if they can be use in such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use type tags, but you need a concrete type to obtain the type tag from. You could add the solution type as type parameter:

```scala
case class Foo[P <: Problem[P], S <: P#Solution:TypeTag]() {
  def doSomething[T:TypeTag](c: ExampleCaseClass[T]) = c match {
    case ExampleCaseClass(s) if typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[S] => "x"
    case ExampleCaseClass(s) => "y"
  }
}
```

If you want a subtype match, use `<:<` instead of `=:=`.

Comment: Seems to be a little bit noisy. What if I have to also pattern match on completely different class within the same block?

Comment: If you need to match types that are eliminated by erasure, I don't think there is a more concise solution, but I would be very happy to hear about it.